# Build Spring eureka client with graalvm native-image

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Am sorry as this is my first question in stack-overflow so i hope i can explain the problem correctly...

Am using `spring boot 3.0.1`
and `GraalVM CE 22.3.0`
and `spring cloud 2022.0.0`

Am trying to build `native-image` of my service that using netflix eureka client.

it shows me the following error when i run my native service:

```
2023-01-01T16:33:42.098+08:00  INFO 16106 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-01T16:33:42.099+08:00 ERROR 16106 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscov    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:351) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArguments(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:206) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1157) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[order-service:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[order-service:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[order-service:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[order-service:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[order-service:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[order-service:3.0.1]
    at com.alammar.orderservice.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:15) ~[order-service:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryClient': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'discoveryClient' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:351) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArguments(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:206) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1157) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1621) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1476) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1363) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:334) ~[na:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[order-service:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:334) ~[na:na]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

---

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.alammar</groupId>
   <artifactId>order-service</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>order-service</name>
   <description>Order service</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
      <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>3.20.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-lra-starter</artifactId>
         <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
         <version>3.20.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
         <version>3.20.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-undertow-starter</artifactId>
         <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
         <version>3.20.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </dependency>

   </dependencies>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>native</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                  <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>build-native</id>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>

   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>netflix-candidates</id>
         <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
         <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

</project>
```

i was expecting to run successfully after i run my native service image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by adding `spring.cloud.refresh.enabled=false`